# View Laravel Artisan Command Signature from CLI

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan

I have a custom artisan command with a signature:

```
protected $signature = 'user:update 
    {changedFrom : Timestamp to update users from - "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss"} 
    {--extras : Whether to update fringe case "extra" users}';
```

I am always forgetting the options and their format. I hoped I'd be able to view them in the CLI but the best I can do is to list the description of commands with `php artisan`.

**Is there an artisan command to see the signature?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding `--help` to the command should output the available options.

```
php artisan user:update --help
```